# Salesforce LWC - Loop through list to display Lightning Design System Tabs

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I am trying to loop through a list in a LWC for each element in the list to display that as a tab. Hereis the code I have so far:
JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  
   test = ["Test1","Test2"]

   
}
```

Heres my HTML:

```
<template>
<template for:each={test} for:item="layer1">
<div key={layer1}>
<div class="slds-tabs_default">
<ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
<li class="slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation">
<a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls= {layer1} id= {layer1}> {layer1}</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id= {layer1} class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby= {layer1}>{layer1} Content</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
</template>
```

It is showing up like this though:
[image]

I am  not able to use SLDS and I am using my own styling thus cannot use the base components like lightning-tabset

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use [base components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) before you try building your own.

There is a [lighnting-tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tabset/example) component that makes this easier.

```
<template>
   <lightning-tabset>
      <template for:each={test} for:item="layer">
        <lightning-tab label="Item One" key={layer}>
           {layer}
        </lightning-tab>
      </template>
     </lightning-tabset>
   </template>
```

The controller

```
 import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

 export default class App extends LightningElement {

     test = ["Test1","Test2"]
  }
```

**Update: Custom LWC Version - Highly recommended to avoid this unless you plan to use custom CSS**.

> Explore [Styling Hooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_css_custom_properties) before you go down this custom path

If you want to purely use LDS and JavaScript and want to go the custom route explore the below sample code

```
<template>
<div class="slds-tabs_default">
    <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
        <template for:each={test} for:item="layer">
            <li class="slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation" key={layer}>
                <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls= {layer} id= {layer}>{layer}</a>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
    <template for:each={test} for:item="layer">
        <div id={layer} class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Test1" key={layer}> Content</div>
    </template>
   </div>
</template>
```

**Edit 2 Updated code**

```
   <template>
     <div class="slds-tabs_default">
       <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
        <template for:each={tabs} for:item="layer">
            <li class="slds-tabs_default__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation" key={layer.Id}>
                <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0"
                    aria-selected="true" aria-controls={layer} id={layer.Id} data-link={layer.Id}
                    onclick={handleClick}>{layer.title}</a>
            </li>
        </template>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs">
        <template for:each={tabs} for:item="layer">
            <div id={layer.Id} class={layer.cssClass} data-id={layer.Id} role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby={layer.Id}
                key={layer.Id}>
                {layer.Content}
            </div>
           </template>
       </div>
     </div>
  </template>
```

JS Controller

```
 import {
    LightningElement,
    track
  } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

  tabs = [{
    title: 'Test1',
    Content: 'Content1',
    Id: '1',
    cssClass: 'slds-tabs_default__content slds-show'
}, {
    title: 'Test2',
    Content: 'Content2',
    Id: '2',
    cssClass: 'slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide'
}];

handleClick(event) {
    this.tabs = this.tabs.map(tab => {
        if(tab.Id === event.target.dataset.link) {
            tab.cssClass = 'slds-tabs_default__content slds-show';
        } else {
            tab.cssClass = 'slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide';
        }
        return tab;
      });
    }
  }
```

To play with this component, use this [url](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/Oj7IfsIHfBNHzezWXOkN)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to use this because I have to use a design system called Newport which is forked from the Lightning Design System and we cannot use the base components which is why I am trying to use the LDS so i can just switch it over to the newport after i can loop through it correctly. Here is link to the newport tab I can trying to create https://thenest-vlocity-storybook.netlify.app/?path=/story/ui-components-tabs--default-default And then I am trying to loop through a list there

Comment: @DrakeDavenport why don't you add that you are not able to use SLDS and you are using your own styling. At least it will provide more content

Comment: I added it, is there anyway to do this without using the base components?

Comment: @DrakeDavenport just updated the answer! Check it out!

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue of them being side by side and not one over the other, but both tabs are clicked and it is showing the content on both tabs for each tab. I will add picture of what it looks like now in the salesforce playground in the regular question

Comment: @DrakeDavenport you will now need to write the JavaScript code to manipulate the CSS to get the click behavior. Also, make an object to add content and data.

Comment: Anyway you can help with that?

Comment: I updated to give you a hint on how to do it. Hope that helps you further learn and explore